# Angular @types/moment-timezone/index.d.ts' not found

Tags: angular

what is the cause of the error ?

Terminal : node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/index.d.ts' not found.

Comment: ERROR in src/typings.d.ts(6,21): error TS6053: File 'C:/Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/index.d.ts' not found.

Comment: This basically means what it sais... The file mentioned is just not found...

Answer (score 0):

May be moment js npm missed. Please try the below solution.

Install moment js npm on your project.

```
npm i moment
```

or

```
install npm
```

Comment: the problem continues

Comment: open CMD->npm i moment. install npm globally.

Comment: Delete all the node module and install again the node modules using the 'install npm' command

Answer (score 0):

Change your code inside the package.json file.

Delete node_modules and package-lock.json from your directory.

Then change the version and run npm install.

```
"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.7",
```

to:

```
"moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
```

Comment: the problem continues